# Give a command that greps files that start with a consonant and the only have vowels after

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I’m not sure how to do this. I tried doing

```
egrep -i ^[^aeiou] [aeiou]$ /usr/share/dict/words
```

But it doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use quotes to protect the regex from the shell?

Comment: Why have you used `prcegrep` as flag? `egrep` does not use PCRE. Do you mean "grep files that start with a consonant" or (what you have coded) "grep a file for words that start with a consonant"?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to quote the expression from the shell:

```
grep -i '^[^aeiou][aeiou]*$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

If you don't do this, the pattern(s) may be expanded to filenames that exists in the current directory. Also, since you inserted a space in-between the two parts of the pattern, `grep` will think that the second part is a filename that should be searched (you will get a "No such file or directory" error).

The `/usr/share/dict/words` file has one word per line, so you can use `-x` and remove the anchors from the expression if you wish:

```
grep -ix '[^aeiou][aeiou]*' /usr/share/dict/words
```

With `-x`, `grep` will only return matches that span the a whole line.

If you *require* a vowel (the above may return single consonant words since `[aeiou]*` matches the empty string):

```
grep -ix '[^aeiou][aeiou][aeiou]*' /usr/share/dict/words
```

or

```
grep -Eix '[^aeiou][aeiou]+' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. quote the regular expression
2. remove the space in between (it will search for it)
3. add a `+` to match one or more vowels (a feature of `egrep` regular expressions)

Try:

```
egrep -i '^[^aeiou][aeiou]+$' /usr/share/dict/words
```